# Why does this code run fine on my Laptop (OSX 10.9), but segfault on server (Linux)?

Tags: c, linux, macos, gcc, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char String[256];

typedef struct LinkedListNode {
String Name;
struct LinkedListNode * Next;
struct LinkedListNode * Friend;
} Node;

typedef Node * NodePointer;


NodePointer InputData(NodePointer Head) {

    String PersonName;
    NodePointer Person;
    int StringLength;
    String FormattedName;
do {    
        printf("Enter nation name :");
        fgets(PersonName,256,stdin);
        if (PersonName[0] != '\n') {
            Person = (NodePointer)malloc(sizeof(NodePointer));
            //copy all except trailing \n
            strncpy(Person->Name, PersonName, strlen(PersonName)-1);
            Person->Next = Head;
            Person->Friend = NULL;
            Head = Person;
        }
    } while (strcmp(PersonName, "\n"));
return Head;
}

void InputAllies(NodePointer Head) {
    String AllyName;
    NodePointer Ally;
    String FormattedName;
    do {    
            printf("Enter best ally for %s :", Head->Name);
            fgets(AllyName,256,stdin);  
            if (AllyName[0] != '\n') {
                Ally = (NodePointer)malloc(sizeof(NodePointer));
                //copy all except trailing \n
                strncpy(Ally->Name, AllyName, strlen(AllyName)-1);
                Head->Friend = Ally;
                Head = Head->Next;
            }
        } while (Head != NULL);
}
```

The part that segfaults specifically is the InputAllies() function, and only with lists with 5 or more elements.  I really have no idea what's going on, but I assume it has something to do with the size of my strings.  Lowering the size of the typedef String causes a segfault after only 3 elements.

Comment: Did valgrind tell you anything?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Your use of `strncpy` is incorrect, `strncpy` does not always null terminate.

Comment: @ouah Agreed. What happens when you try `strlcpy(Person->name, PeronName, 256)`? Also, please replace the sentinel `256` value with a macro, like `#define BUF_LENGTH (256)`.

Comment: Valgrind complained multiple times about invalid writes and reads of size 8 to addresses not stack'd malloc'd or free'd.

Answer (score 4):

I think that in function `InputData`, just after the `strncpy`, you are forgetting to add the final `'\0'` to the string `Person->Name`.  The problem is when you print the string.  On your Mac, it seems that there is a null character that happens to be magically in the right place; on the Linux server, you're not so lucky.

Copying from the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy):

> The  `strcpy()`  function  copies the string pointed to by `src`,
>   including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer  pointed  to
>   by  `dest`. The  strings  may  not overlap, and the destination string
>   dest must be large enough to receive the copy.
>
> The `strncpy()` function is similar, except that at most `n` bytes  of 
>   `src` are  copied.  Warning: If there is no null byte among the first `n`
>   bytes of `src`, the string placed in `dest` will not be null-terminated.

So your problem is the last sentence, and it will happen only when your source string cannot fit in the first `n` bytes of your target string.  I think that's exactly your case here, as you're setting `n` to be less than the `strlen` of your source string.  In any case, there may be other bugs in your code too.  Check with a debugger or valgrind.

BTW, I don't understand why you want `strncpy` there, as your source and target strings are necessarily of the same length.  Why not use `strcpy` instead?

Comment: Actually in [mac strncpy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strncpy.3.html) null terminates the result if src string length is less than dest string length. While this is not the case in [linux](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/strncpy.html).

Comment: I wasn't using strcpy because I didn't want to include the newline from frets. Perhaps replacing the newline character in the string with '\0' would work better.  I could've sworn I read all I could about strncpy.  Thanks for your help.